# Using curl I added the header "HTTP_X_REAL_IP", on the server side it becomes "HTTP_HTTP_X_REAL_IP"

Tags: linux, curl, web

This is my curl script:

```
curl -H "HTTP_X_REAL_IP: ip" "domain"
```

This is my server environment:

```
> 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'SERVER_PORT': '9646', 'REMOTE_PORT': '55278',
> 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/0.13.4',
> 'HTTP_HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '0.0.0.0',
```

Comment: The server adds `HTTP` in front of it to denote its origin, the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HTTP_" is added in front of each of the header names received during the HTTP request by the PHP engine. The proper header name to use is "X-Real-IP".

Comment: “REMOTE_ADDR”,“HTTP_X_REAL_IP” and “HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR” whose the proper head are what  in python?

Comment: "REMOTE_ADDR" is determined by low-level access to the socket. The other two result from the `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP headers.